# Load the external js files in angular js modal popup or partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modalpopup

I am developing angularJS application and using asp.net mvc as well. 
I want to open a modal popup from angularJS and then in that popup "View" of mvc is rendered.

The problem I am facing that popup is opening but the js files are not loaded in modal popup. Please help me in this matter of loading the js files in modal popup.

code

```
    // main angular js
angular.module('PopUpModule', ['ngResource','ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'uigridApp'])
    .controller("ModalDemoCtrl", function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, $window) {
    $scope.open = function (size) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'UiGridDemo.html',
                    controller: 'uigridCtrl',
                    size: 'lg',
                    backdrop:'static',
                    windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
                              resolve: {
                        '$uibModalInstance': function () {
                            return function () { return modalInstance; }
                        }
                    }

                });
```

//modal popup (view of mvc .cshtml file)

```
         //script
<script src="Script/Script2.js"></script>

       <body>
                //html code goes here
    </body>
```

problem is i want to load js script(Script2.js) which is having "jquery code" that should get loaded in modal popup which is view(.cshtml) of mvc modal popup is open through angular.but  it is does not load(Script2.js).I checked with chrome dev.tools. how to load it help  me with this

Comment: post relevant code

Comment: you don't need to load js files in your partial. just add those files in the parent view. they'll be available in the partial as well. maybe we can help more if you post the code.

Comment: will need to see some code

Comment: If the modal popup has access to the app scope of the JS, you shouldn't have problems... but please show us some of your code so we can understand better your predicament...

Comment: Actually i dont want to add in the parent view, i want load the(Script2.js) in the n the modal pop up..in which jquery functions are defined. should get loaded when popup opens.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer if i load the js file in the parent file from which i am opening modal popup.This file will be available to this modal pop up,

Answer (score 0):

I think uigridCtrl is not loaded in index.html check whether the js file is loaded in index.html, and in open method no need to mention controller property. It will reinitialize the controller.

Edit - if uigridCtrl is same as parent html's controller no need to mention in pop up html. It will share the same scope as parent html.

Comment: i have added reference of script in index.html in which uigridctrl is defined .. and controller is diiferent parent and child.. i want to load script2.js in popup(view of mvc)..which is not loading

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by me can be used in future by you in case you don't want to add the file or modify the code in the parent controller/directive. You have to add few additional parameters as well. It works perfectly and I don't have to make any modification to the parent. I am providing the code from the live working application.

```
 $ocLazyLoad.load({
    name: '', // Module Name - Optional
    files: [
        'viewRequestController.js',
        'request-tpl.js'
    ]
 })
 .then(function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'viewRequest.html',
        controller: 'popupCtrl',
        controllerAs:'ctrl',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {
            initVars: function(){
                return initVars;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(
        function(response) { },
        function(response) {
            // Executes code when your modal closes.
        }
    );
});
```

Add $ocLozyLoad and $modal parameter. I hope it is useful for you.